# bundling a small task to make all dependencies available in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, puppeteer

I have been personally using puppeteer for a lot of deployment and UI testing tasks.

But the issue I face now is that the more supporting code I have the harder to make it available directly in the browser.

What I usually do is that I place all the code I will use in the browser in a single file, encode the whole module as text, make it available to the browser and use a dynamic import in the browser. You see where I am getting, hopefully...

If I try to add 3rd party libs then this whole setup falls apart because I can't make all dependencies available in a single file.

Question is: Anyone has used any patterns for that? Is bundling an option here? any examples? Thanks a lot...

Comment: You could import said modules from a CDN. I'm curious as to why you need to do this in the first place, are you loading in stuff like lodash etc for testing purposes?

Comment: That is a good idea, I could use the dist version from unpkg. I mostly used it locally to deploy SharePoint assets as code. So the whole site is defined as code.

 You have similar things with pnp but that requires more accesses than just being a site owner.

If you can put it as an answer I would accept it, I have not thought about CDN's... haha

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add that as a possible answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I suggested in my inquiry above, one solution for external packages is to load them in through a CDN.

So

```
var scriptElm = document.createElement('script');
scriptElm.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(scriptElm);
```

You'd have to ensure that it is properly loaded before trying to use it, but that should be easy enough.

EDIT:

If I am using CDN's I might just as well import them directly to the consumer file ex:

```
import lodash from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js';
```